# Is there a email client similar to mailplane for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, gmail, email-client

I've been impressed with MailPlane, the email client for the Mac that is designed for gmail.  Is there a similar gmail client for Windows?

Comment: I hope you are looking at their `Do you want Mailplane for Windows?` page (http://mailplaneapp.com/windows/). And, have stated your interest there...

Comment: Google had a few good hits...https://encrypted.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Windows+gmail+client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be nothing near [Mailplane Gmail client](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2010/092110-mailplane-gmail-client-updated-to.html?source=nww_rss) on Windows, in general.
Meanwhile, there are still hopes of getting a [Mailplane for Windows](http://groups.google.com/group/mailplaneapp/browse_thread/thread/ec4753a6109318c0) edition.
Other [alternatives to Mailplane](http://alternativeto.net/software/mailplane/?platform=windows) don't sound interesting enough.
There is [Prism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Prism#page-files) from Mozilla -- which could be investigated further...

One good idea would be to point everyone interested in the Windows edition to
the '[`Do you want Mailplane for Windows?`](http://mailplaneapp.com/windows/)' page.
<sup>ps: This is a somewhat ad-hoc answer based on my sudden interest in MailPlane.</sup>